# Como cadastrar, consultar e exibir dados na mesma requisição?

Tags: ajax, banco-de-dados, select

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário insere seus dados (nome, experiência, altura e peso), as informações são cadastradas no banco, comparadas e é retornado para o usuário o modelo de prancha ideal de acordo com as informações dele, dentro de um `modal`. Tudo isso já está feito e funcionando.

O problema é que, obviamente, como o `SELECT` já está dentro do código, assim que a página é carregada a REQUISIÇÃO no banco já está feita! E tenho como retorno o último usuário que cadastrou suas informações no banco.

O usuário tem que inserir seus dados no `form`, os dados dele é cadastrado no banco, é feita a comparação e o retorno com o resultado seja exibido na MESMA requisição.

[image: Desta forma]

Até agora, o que fiz:

Aqui é feito o `SELECT`. A comparação dos dados no BD:

```
function BuscaAlgo($conexao){
$query = "SELECT  USU.usuario,
                 USU.nome,
                 USU.exp,
                 USU.altura,
                 USU.peso,
                 PRAN.exp_ref,
                 PRAN.altura_ref,
                 PRAN.peso_ref,
                 PRAN.tipo_prancha,
                 PRAN.tamanho_prancha, 
                 PRAN.meio_prancha, 
                 PRAN.litragem_prancha       
                  FROM DADOS_USUARIO AS USU 
                       INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN
                           on USU.exp = PRAN.exp_ref
                            WHERE USU.altura = PRAN.altura_ref
                              AND USU.peso = PRAN.peso_ref
                                ORDER BY USU.usuario DESC LIMIT 1"; 

  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

  $retorno = array();

  while($experiencia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $retorno[] = $experiencia;
  }
 return $resultado;
}
```

Aqui exibe o resultado do `SELECT` feito no banco:

```
include "banco.php";    

$resultado = array();
$resultado = BuscaAlgo($conexao);

foreach($resultado as $valor){
  echo $valor['usuario']; print('.  .'); 
  echo $valor['nome']; print('.  .'); 
  echo $valor['exp']; print('.  .'); 
  echo $valor['altura']; print('.  .'); 
  echo $valor['peso']; print('.  .'); 
  print('///////');
  echo $valor['tipo_prancha']; print('.  .'); 
  echo $valor['tamanho_prancha']; print('.  .'); 
  echo $valor['meio_prancha']; print('.  .'); 
  echo $valor['litragem_prancha'];  
}
```

(Ignorem a parte visual. Neste momento, o objetivo é só trazer o resultado mesmo)

Como posso fazer isso dentro da mesma requisição?
Qual a melhor forma de fazer e como?

Comment: Quando faz esses `echos` finais não são retornados para o cliente? Você vẽ alguma coisa impressa?

Comment: Sim! Esses `echos` me retornam exatamente o que eu quero! Ele exibe o `SELECT` que eu fiz.

Comment: Porque faz a requisição ao banco logo no carregamento da página e não só na submição dos dados do cliente?

Comment: Creio que isso esteja acontecendo porque o código de cadastro e consulta está depois do fechamento do `</html>`. É necessário criar um arquivo para cada ação?

Comment: Não é necessário, apenas coloque uma condição, que diz para só executar isso caso o form seja submitido: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { Cadastrar, consultar, exibir...` . Presumo que esteja a usar o method post no form certo?

Comment: tem algum arquivo js ?? Para requisições sem mudar de páginas sugiro você usar o AJAX . E se você tiver usando JQuery usar o $.ajax({})

Comment: Sim, método `POSTS`. Eu estou utilizando o AJAX para bloquear o refresh da página, pois quando o form é submetido, os dados são enviados, a página é atualizada e o modal é exibido. O modal tem que ser exibido sem a página dar refresh, por isso o AJAX.

Comment: Vou atualizar meu código e trago o feedback.

Comment: @Miguel Coloquei a `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']{`, no `cadastra` e `consulta` ele funciona, porém nos `echos`, código que imprime o resultado na tela ele não funciona. Tentei de diferentes formas, em diferentes posições e nada :/

Comment: Ha ok, com ajax é diferente. Mas a requisição só enviada quando faz o submit do form certo? Então como carrega outros dados

Comment: Como seria com AJAX?

Comment: Talvez ajude http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp